# How to add an array to an array object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, api, object

How do I make `object1` to `object2`? It's a JSON type from an API so I can't just manually put the value of array inside the object. Z is actually var z = [4,5,6]; a completely separate array.

```
var object1  = {
  value:[{
    "x": "apple",
    "y": [1,2,3]
 }]
};

var object2 = {
  value:[{
    "x": "apple",
    "y": [1,2,3],
    "z": [4,5,6]
  }]
};
```

Comment: Why are you not able to manipulate the object with `value` to set `z` to `[456]`?

Comment: so var z = [4,5,6]; is a separate array, It's not a specified field inside the object2

Comment: Try: `object1.value[0].z = z;`

Comment: wow object1.value[0].z = z; actually worked! thanks a lot :D

Comment: so... what about var object2 = {...object1, z: [4, 5, 6]}?

Answer (score 1):

You can just access the array and update it:

```js
const updateObjectAtIndex = (arr, index, newData) => {
  const clone = [...arr];
  const result = {
    ...clone[index],
    ...newData
  };
  
  clone[index] = result;
  
  return clone;
}

var object1  = {
  value:[{
    "x": "apple",
    "y": [1,2,3]
 }]
};

var object2 = {
  ...object1,
  value: updateObjectAtIndex(object1.value, 0, {z: [4, 5, 6]})
}

console.dir(object2)
```

Comment: Why not just `object1.value[0].z = [4, 5, 6]` ?

Comment: @Titus because that would mutate `object1`, so you'd have both with `z` set to `[4, 5, 6]`. Don't know if that's an issue here but the question seems to imply they want separate objects

Comment: I think I want what @Titus mentioned. Thanks for answering though, Oliver.

Comment: Oh, I see, I've interpreted `object1...object2` as different states of the same object rather then two different objects.

Comment: @Titus it seems as though that was correct in any case, so all's well that ends well ha

Answer (score 0):

> The `Object.assign()` method is used to copy the values of all
>   enumerable own properties from one or more source objects to a target
>   object. It will return the target object.

```js
var object1  = {
  value:[{
    "x": "apple",
    "y": [1,2,3]
 }]
};

var object2 = {
  value:[{
    "x": "apple",
    "y": [1,2,3],
    "z": [4,5,6]
  }]
};

const object3 = Object.assign(object1, object2);

console.log(object3);
```